# Escaping closure in swift and how to perform it in Java

Tags: java, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I'm developing an app for both iOS and Java and in my swift program I have a function that uses an escaping closure that passes an array of strings. In swift, it's func definition goes as

```
func foo(uid: String, onComplete: @escaping([String]) -> Void { 
    onComplete(someStringArray)
}
```

and its func call is

```
class.foo(uid: player1, onComplete { (stringArray) in {
    do something with stringArray
}
```

My main focus is now figuring that out for Java. The BIG issue is I'm using Google's Firebase Database which loads data asynchronously so simply making a return function won't work since the return will be called before all the data is loaded. I've heard of maybe call backs, but I figured I'd ask here first before I spend precious hours on the wrong task. I'm thinking the Java version would be

```
void foo(String uid, onComplete...) { 
onComplete(someStringArray)
}
```

Anyways I hope I was as detailed as possible and appreciate any help at all!
-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Here is an example:

```java
public class LambdaExample{
    
    interface OnCompletion {
        void onCompletion(String msg);
    }

    public static void performAction(String msg, OnCompletion completion){
        completion.onCompletion(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        String msg = "Congratulations! ";
        performAction(
            msg,
            // Implement interface method. Add your own definition.
            (x) -> {
                System.out.println(x + "Code completed.");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a godsend